# AWS NFS mount volume issue in kubernetes cluster (EKS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nfs, amazon-efs

I am using AWS EKS. As i am trying to mount efs to my eks cluster, getting the following error.

```
Warning  FailedMount  3m1s  kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[nfs-client-root], unattached volumes=[nfs-client-root nfs-client-provisioner-token-8bx56]: timed out waiting for the condition
 Warning  FailedMount  77s   kubelet  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "nfs-client-root" : mount failed: exit status 32
```

Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/b07f3f15-b655-435c-8ec1-8d14b8690c1d/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs-client-root --scope -- mount -t nfs 172.31.26.154:/mnt/nfs_share/ /var/lib/kubelet/pods/b07f3f15-b655-435c-8ec1-8d14b8690c1d/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs-client-root
Output: Running scope as unit run-23226.scope.
mount.nfs: Connection timed out

And also i tried to connect with external nfs server, also getting the same warning message.

i have opened the inbound allow all traffic in eks cluster, efs and nfs security groups.

If it is the problem with nodes to install nfs-common, please let me know the steps how to install the nfs-common package inside the nodes.
As i am using AWS EKS, i am unable to login to the nodes.

Comment: Did you follow the instruction on how to install the CSI provisioner [csi-provisioner-instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html) ? Also how are you provisioning the PV / PVC? Can you add any pertinent yaml file to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

While creating an ec2 machine for an external NFS-server, you must add it to the vpc used by the eks cluster and include it in the security group that nodes use to communicate with each other.